# Pytorch get "reduced" tensor by indices

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor `a = torch.arange(6).reshape(2,3)`, and another tensor `b=(torch.rand(a.size())> 0.5).int().nonzero()`.

I want to create a new tensor that contains only values from `a` of the indices that are indicated by `b`.

For example:

```
a = torch.arange(6).reshape(2,3) # tensor([[0, 1, 2],
                                 #         [3, 4, 5]])
b = (torch.rand(a.size())> 0.5).int().nonzero() # tensor([[0, 1],
                                                #         [0, 2],
                                                #         [1, 0],
                                                #         [1, 1]])
```

The desired output is:

`tensor([1,2,3,4])`

I know that I can iterate over the values of `b` and access those values in `a` as indices but I wanted to know if there is a better `Pytorch` way to to this (using tensor operations only).

** The shape of the output tensor doesn't really matter, I just need to have a tensor with only the values indicated by `b`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can do:

```py
a[b[:,0], b[:,1]]
```

This will produce a 1D tensor with the values at the indices specified by `b`. Note that the output might not be the same from run to run of the program since the indices are selected nondeterministically.

---

If you don't know the number of dimension in advance, you'll need to use `map()` to generate the desired slices:

```py
a[tuple(map(lambda x: b[:,x], range(a.dim())))]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, however the shape of `a` is actually unknown, can this solution be expanded?

Comment: Shape as in the number of dimensions?

Comment: Yes (the (2,3) was just for the example)

Comment: @ChikChak Done -- see my edit.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Last question - can it be done with only Pytorch operations? So that all of the operations can be executed on GPU.

Comment: You might be able to use `vmap` in PyTorch, but I'm not sure if it will provide any speedup.